# Get Rid of inSync

Tags: uninstall, google-drive, insync

I'm new here, so I'm not totally sure if this question would be appropriate for these forums, but anyways... How can I uninstall inSync from my computer. I didn't like the service and so, I disconnected it from my Google account. But, I can't get it off my computer. I do use Ubuntu as my only OS, and I have a 64 bit computer. Also, if I disconnect inSync from my Google Account, will it still send me emails? I'm just wondering. Please reply!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove insync`? (or what the package name of insync now is.)

Answer (score 9):

The version of the software has changed (as of August 2013), so the answer from ubuntu_tr above may need to be tweaked. To remove the latest non-beta version of insync type

```
sudo apt-get purge insync && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and type 'Y' to confirm. Then to delete the remaining insync folder type

```
sudo rmdir /usr/lib/insync --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
```

Then go to Ubuntu Software Centre, move the mouse near the top of your screen to view menu options and click on `Edit->Software sources...` select the `Other software` tab and then scroll down, select `apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu` and click the `Remove` button.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge insync-beta-ubuntu && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This command will remove it. You should also remove ppa entry from the "software sources > Other Software" section

[Reference](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/03/insyncgoogle-drive-client-for-linux-out-of-beta-for-windows-and-mac/)

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is an old question, but I just wanted to add an up-to-date answer.*

According to the official uninstall instructions on [How to uninstall Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/uninstall):

**Debian/Ubuntu**

1. Run `sudo apt-get remove insync`.
2. Delete the application data folder at `~/.config/Insync`.

**Fedora**

1. Run `sudo yum remove insync`.
2. Delete the application data folder at `~/.config/Insync`.

Answer (score 1):

InSync adds a startup item to Gnome. You can run `gnome-sessions-properties` from command line to remove or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick `sudo apt-get remove insync-beta` will do make sure its not running in the background just in case it gives you problems.

Answer (score 0):

For beta1 (which installed from a tarball using a python script) the answer is [on the insync forums](https://support.insynchq.com/forums/discussion/1368/how-do-i-uninstall-insync-from-my-ubuntu-system):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/insync /usr/bin/insync-set /usr/bin/insync-get /usr/lib/insync
rm ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/insync_plugin.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Insync causes a warning in sudo apt update in Ubuntu 18.04 beta-2 even though all of the methods shown above are taken to remove Insync.

The answer is to remove the repository in Software Boutique. There appears to be no way to remove the Authentication key in Synaptic, but it can be removed in Software Boutique. After removal, the problem shown in sudo apt update is gone.